# In python when passing arguments what does ** before an argument do?

Tags: python

From reading this example and from my slim knowledge of Python it must be a shortcut for converting an array to a dictionary or something?

```
class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        return render.hello(name=name)
        # Another way:
        #return render.hello(**locals())
```

Comment: Actually this is not really a duplicate. This questions asks what calling a function with `f(**d)` means, while the other question seems to be more about `*` and `**` in function parameter definitions.

Answer (score 12):

In python `f(**d)` passes the values in the dictionary `d` as keyword parameters to the function `f`. Similarly `f(*a)` passes the values from the array `a` as positional parameters.

As an example:

```
def f(count, msg):
  for i in range(count):
    print msg
```

Calling this function with `**d` or `*a`:

```
>>> d = {'count': 2, 'msg': "abc"}
>>> f(**d)
abc
abc
>>> a = [1, "xyz"]
>>> f(*a)
xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

It "unpacks" an dictionary as an argument list.
ie:

```
def somefunction(keyword1, anotherkeyword):
   pass
```

it could be called as

```
somefunction(keyword1=something, anotherkeyword=something)
or as
di = {'keyword1' : 'something', anotherkeyword : 'something'}
somefunction(**di)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python docuemntation, 5.3.4](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#primaries):

> If any keyword argument does not correspond to a formal parameter name, a TypeError exception is raised, unless a formal parameter using the syntax **identifier is present; in this case, that formal parameter receives a dictionary containing the excess keyword arguments (using the keywords as keys and the argument values as corresponding values), or a (new) empty dictionary if there were no excess keyword arguments.

This is also used for [the power operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator), in a different context.

Answer (score 1):

**local() passes the dictionary corresponding to the local namespace of the caller.  When passing a function with ** a dictionary is passed, this allows variable length argument lists.